# how to check whether the string was present in another string only from string start in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, string, url, string-comparison

I want to check one `url` is part of `main_url` or not in rails.

i come across some string methods like `include` or `match` to check this. but these methods are returning true if sub string matches in main string.

But i want to check that the sub url should match main url, right from starting letter to anywhere in main_url then only it should return `true` other wise it should return `false`

i am looking some library methods like below.

`"/programming/ruby/help".some_library_method("/programming/") => return true` (as its matching from right from beginning of string.)

`"/programming/ruby/help".some_library_method("/ruby/") => return false` (as its not matching right from beginning of string.)

```
"/programming/ruby/help".some_library_method("/programming/ruby/") => return true
```

`"/programming/ruby/help".some_library_method("/programming/ruby/help") => return true` even if it matches fully also it should return true

should i use string library or is there any url library present for this?

Comment: `"/programming/ruby/help".start_with?("/programming/")`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [start_with?()](https://www.rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/String:start_with%3F)

```
my_string = "/programming/ruby/help"
puts my_string.start_with?('/programming')
true
```